# Its possbile handle a JSON file with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, client-side

I am developing a solution to a challenge proposed to me by a company. The chanllenge is develop a ReactJS app and its required to store some datas in a JSON file, but in no time its required to build some service or API, just a ReactJS app and as far as I know its not possible handle files in client-side(write).

Comment: Sure you can :) Just don't think about writing the file directly -- that's not possible client-side -- but you can definitely trigger a download of a generated file :)

Answer (score 0):

To set:

```
let jsonObj = {"name": "Bob", "age": 100}

localStorage.setItem('userList', JSON.stringify(jsonObj))
```

To retrieve:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userList')))
 // {name: "Bob", age: 100}
```

You can also try this link for implementing with React:
https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/localstorage-react/

Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53864791/11857649